# How to get a common raw output encoding with git diff?

Tags: git, unicode, encoding

We first assume I am using *utf-8* as default:

```
LESSCHARSET=UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Now, let's consider this example:

```
git init
touch unicode latin
git add unicode latin
echo "Déjà-vu" > unicode
iconv -f utf-8 -t latin1 unicode > latin
git --no-pager diff
```

Where I will get:

```
diff --git a/latin b/latin
index e69de29..cc65db5 100644
--- a/latin
+++ b/latin
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+D<E9>j<E0>-vu
diff --git a/unicode b/unicode
index e69de29..58804c6 100644
--- a/unicode
+++ b/unicode
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Déjà-vu
```

Of course if I set `$LANG` to latin1 I will have the opposite problem where Déjà-vu is unreadable for `latin1`.

> How can tell Git to automatically adjust the file encoding to a common
>   output encoding?